What is the meaning of a 28k pull-up resistor in an USB A-to-C cable?
Since that debacle a few years ago, I assembled a small test harness where I plug every new A-to-C cable that I get to check for the 56k pull-up resistor between CC and Vin and toss out the ones that don't comply.
Recently I got a car phone charger with such a cable and didn't test it before using it. Luckily nothing bad happened, but the phone complained of "slow charging", so I unplugged it immediately. When I got home, I plugged the cable into the tester and it reported a 28k resistor.
I couldn't find any documentation mentioning a 28k resistor besides the 56k, 22k, and 10k (± tolerance).
I will probably toss this cable, but I'm curious if there is any meaning to this resistor value.

How are you testing it? Perhaps the measurement is wrong due to some reason. Maybe there is no simple resistance between VBUS and CC? Is it an active cable which requires power? Technically, the resistance is irrelevant, as long as the device sees correct voltage when it applies correct loading. So current sources are valid when used in place of resistor.

HI @Justme, I'm testing the same way I tested other cables, just connecting the cable to a breakout board and measuring the resistance between Vin and CC. Usually it either shows 56k or infinite (the latter for bad cables). My phone (a Pixel 6, if that matters) found it as confusing as me, apparently.

Details missing. Ok so the cable could be weird, but 28k is also exactly half of 56k. Your test setup is also unknown, have you got two separate CC pins from the connector or does your breakout board shot the two CC pins together?

2 pins for CC but just one Vin and Gnd.

Well, you need to make more tests then. Plug the Type-A into a PC and measure the voltages of both CC pins separately when pulled down with two separate 5.1k resistors, one on each CC pin. Only by observing how the CC pins behave when cable is plugged between devices you are able to understand if the cable is designed wrong or not. If it does not work, it may simply have a manufacturing error.
